# IF statement inside where clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a calendar app. It stores times in two formats. The table have following columns `title, startDate, startTime`. If the user provides start time plus start date. The database stores UNIX time stamp(number of seconds since UNIX epok) in the column `startTime`, while startDate is `NULL`. If the user only provide a start date,  the database stores the date in format `nnnn-mm-dd` in `startDate` and `NULL` in ´startTime`. I have this DB structure, because it's easier to display times around the world, because different timezones have different daylight saving times.

I want select the events that are occurring after a specified date. The client computer provide the server with a UNIX timestamp of the beginning of that day(`$unix`) and a date(`$date`) in the format `nnnn-mm-dd` to select the correct dates.

The problem is, I don't know how to select those days that are occurring as specified above. This solution is not applicable for me, even though it works:

```
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE startDate >= '$date'
   OR startTime >= '$unix'
```

The thing is I have in some rows where unix time stamp is provided in `startTime`, I also have a date provided in `startDate` and other reason I which I don't want to explain. And because of that I can't use the solution above.

I need some kind of solution that have an IF statement inside the Where clause like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE IF(startTime = NULL, startDate >= '$date', startTime >= '$unix')
```

I'm just guessing this solution. But is it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WHERE (startTime IS NULL AND startDate >= '$date')
   OR (startTime IS NOT NULL AND startTime >= '$unix')
```

Comment: @Woho87 : you can never have enough NULL! ;)

Comment: @Woho87: there is no two nulls. Was in the first revision but I fixed that typo after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

All SQL dialects support CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT *
 FROM events
WHERE CASE WHEN startTime is null
           THEN startDate >= '$date'
           ELSE startTime >= '$unix'
```

Comment: And this will not be optimized to be using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need some combined boolean logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events
WHERE 
    (startDate IS NULL AND startTime >= '$unix') OR
    (startTime IS NULL AND startDate >= '$date')
```

Comment: Are you sure we need `IS NULL` in both cases? If so - why don't move it out the parentheses.

Comment: @zerkms: different variables...I'm going by my interpretation of the posters requirements, which may or may not be correct:  "The "database stores UNIX time stamp(number of seconds since UNIX epok) in the column startTime, while startDate is NULL. If the user only provide a start date, the database stores the date in format nnnn-mm-dd in startDate and NULL in ´startTime`.

Comment: hehe, and I tried to write my answer according his `IF` supposition... Which represents different logic :-S

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE 
  (startDate >= '$date' OR startTime >= '$unix')
AND 
  startDate != NULL
```

This will not return any row that has null value for startDate

Comment: `!= NULL` is always evaluated to `FALSE`

Comment: `AND startDate IS NOT NULL` is what you're looking for there @Ibu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to use startDate when startDate is not null, and startTime when startTime is not null... then try this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM events
WHERE (startTime is not NULL and startDate >= '$date') 
OR (startTime is not NULL and startTime >= '$unix')
```

You can use the CASE statement also, but this makes more sense is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I think this is the best way to proceed...

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE IF(startTime IS NULL, '$date', '$unix') =< startDate
```